# Silex with 404 page

Tags: php, silex

I create controller in controllers/Redirect/Myredierct.php
There i have such code

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\Controllers\Redirect;

use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;


abstract class errorController 
{
    public function errorAction(Application $app)
    {
      $app->error(
        function(\Exception $e) use ($app) {
            if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException && $e->getStatusCode() == 404) {
                return $this->app['twig']->render('error.html.twig');
            }
        }
    );}
}
```

My question is where i must include it? I can't understand how i can use my code. Please, help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two questions in your post : the 404 status and how to use your abstract controller.

First, there is an error in the naming of you file / class : your class should be named like the file. Moreover, I do not know if it is mandatory or just good practice, but your file should always end with "Controller", so what I would do is rename your file to "ErrorController.php", and your class to "ErrorController".

Now, you have an abstract class, which means it is meant to be used by another controller through inheritance. The way to use this would be to create a new controller like this one :

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\Controllers;

class YourControllerName extends errorController {
     // Whatever you want
     public function whateverAction(Application $app)
     {
     // You can use you parent controller this way
     $this->errorAction($app);
          ...
     return $response;
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.